# Bash Customizations

Tags: linux, bash, customization

While I use Linux, I have not yet customized my bash shell, which I use a fair amount.  So, I ask:  What are your favorite customizations you have for bash?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257236/the-shell-dotfile-cookbook among many others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom prompt is my first one. I've never liked the '$' :)

Mine own prompt is very personal to me though. It's multi-line for a start, which a lot of people aren't fans of, but it suits me fine. It's also version control system enabled - it'll report svn revisions / git branches if you're in a source tree.

Comment: Which suggests a link to pastebin or something...

Comment: Your wish etc...
http://pastebin.com/m8d69059

Comment: Except that's ruined the non-ascii characters. /me hunts for a better pastebin.

Comment: http://www.pastie.org/496585  <-- that one worked a lot better.

Comment: nice, but I don't like the colors.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at `zsh`.

It is much more powerful, and you're ready for it if you're asking about shell customization.

Some killer features are path expansion:

```
cd /u/l/X<TAB> -> cd /usr/local/X11
```

and globbing

```
wc -l **/*.xml
```

(bash3 also does that, so there's some improvement)

And it is smart enough, so

```
for i in .*; do cp $i dotfiles; done
```

wouldn't land you in trouble or fail epically.

And it have a lot of options and a massive completions library.

Answer (score 1):

- A bunch of aliases, some for typos some just to give me the behavior I want by default, some for less keystrokes.

  - emcas to emacs
  - ls to ls -lt
  - pu to pushd
  - po to popd

Answer (score 0):

An important one for me is to add some color to the prompt. That makes it act as a visual delimiter when I've got two sets of output. I can easily see where one ends and the next begins.

Answer (score 0):

- [Colorize your command prompt](http://lifehacker.com/202042/ask-lifehacker--how-do-i-customize-my-command-line-prompt)
- Enable some shell options:

  ```
  # Make bash append rather than overwrite the history on disk
  shopt -s histappend
  # Enable cool globbing wildcards
  shopt -s extglob
  ```
- Add some aliases:

  ```
  alias ls="ls --color=auto"
  alias hd="hexdump -C"
  ```
- Colorize `grep` output:

  ```
  export GREP_OPTIONS=--color=auto
  export GREP_COLORS='ms=01;36'
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Settings for the other prompts (continuation lines, select, execution trace):

```
#---------------------------------------------------
#  set Bash prompts
#---------------------------------------------------
export PS2='continue> '
export PS3='choose: '
export PS4='[$LINENO $SECONDS] '
```

Answer (score 0):

I second the zsh suggestion. Though I'm pretty sure most of these will work in bash as well.

Notice the lowercase=command upercase=suffix-command convention. (some of these come from the [zsh-lovers manpage](http://grml.org/zsh/zsh-lovers.html))

```
alias -g bigfiles="find . -size +50000k -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print \$8 \": \" \$5 }'"
alias -g f="find . -name"
alias -g G='| egrep'
alias -g g="grep"
alias -g H='| head'
alias -g LL="2>&1 | less"
alias -g L="| less"
alias -g NUL="> /dev/null 2>&1"
```

As an ubuntu user:

```
alias 'Ag'='sudo apt-get install'
alias 'As'='apt-cache search'
alias 'Ai'='apt-cache show'
alias 'Ar'='sudo apt-get remove'
alias 'Au'='sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade'
```

As a ruby user

```
alias Gs='gem search --remote'
alias Gg='sudo gem install'
alias Gi='gem specification'
```

Also you might spend a little time wading through: http://dotfiles.org/.bashrc.
There are a number of gems over there.

Answer (score 0):

1. I usually make sure to set up [Bash Completion](http://www.caliban.org/bash/), because it I've gotten so used to it that it annoys me when I can't tab-complete hostnames with ssh.
2. I set up my prompt command so that the titles of all my terminal windows tell me what host and directory I'm in:

   ```
   export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${HOSTNAME}:${PWD}\007"'
   ```

   This way I don't get a bunch of windows titled "xterm" or "Terminal" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I have a ton of stuff for customizations: first there is:

```
function add
{
cd;
echo "alias $*" >>~/bash/aliases.sh;
source ~/bash/aliases.sh;
cd -;
}
```

which adds aliases to my ~/bash/aliases file, which is sourced by my .bashrc file.
one of which that I really like is:

alias programs='echo $PATH | sed "s/:/ /g" | xargs ls'

which can be used with grep to get all kinds of stuff.

I also have this which is really helpful:

```
function up
{
    if [ "$1" = "" ];
    then
            cd ..;
        return;
    fi

    NUM_TIMES=$( echo $(($1 - 1)) );

    for ((x=0;$x<=$NUM_TIMES; x++))
    do
        cd ..;
    done;
}
```

which I have in my ~/bash/functions file, which is just a few of the things I have added to bash